# Jquery: select "DIV ID" and "LI CLASS" and "LINK" text

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I want to select **"#container"** and **".active"** and add **"a"** tags text **"link here"** to a variable and the log it.

```
  <div id="container">
        <div id="head"></div>
        <div id="body"></div>
        <ul>
            <li class="item active">
                 <a class="link">link here</a>
            </li>
            <li class="item"></li>
            <li class="item"></li>
            <li class="item"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Here is my code so far... cant see the problem in it.. tried everything.

```
var tabid = $('#container.active a').text();
console.log(tabid);
```

Thanks for all help guys! peace out.

Comment: you need a space before `.active`

Comment: Have also tried that, did not work...

Comment: what ever I do I just get "(an empty string)" in console window

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Tentonaxe/A8NAm/ do you have duplicate elements with an `id="container"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is missing a space.
use:

```
$('#container .active a')
```

or better, if your html structure stays the same:

```
$('#container > ul > li.active > a')
```

also, you have to make sure your code is executed after the DOM is ready:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var text = $('#container > ul > li.active > a').text();
console.log(text);

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$('#container .active a').text();
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding a space before `.active`, and it works.

see http://jsfiddle.net/w5U8Q/